# ebook store that shows book without download options

Tags: php

Client wants to have online ebook store, so users can read books online only READONLy (without option to download them or copy content).

I assume that those books will be in PDF format stored on server (or it could be other format if there is some that is better for this task?!).

I was trying to find something in google about this, but without any luck. Probably, I was using incorrect keywords liek "displaying pdf without download option" etc. 
I know that ebook stores has some functionality like this.

Can you, please, give me some clues:

- what is the concept, how this could be done (show content, but restrict users to downoad content)?
- is it difficult task or there are some existing libraries (commercial or non-commercial) for this task?

The store would be written in PHP, but I can use other technologies if this makes it easier.

I understand that nothing is 100% for sure, I just need some ways to make it harder to steal for "normal" users.

I want to note that all content that client wants to publish is 100% legal for pubishing (clien has rights to publish those ebooks).

Comment: You need to google for PDF copyright protection. It has nothing to do with the server. It's an Adobe feature of the PDF viewer. There are multiple levels of protection from disabling save/print to binding to a computers MAC address. While none are perfect the features are there.

Comment: But I have seen web sites, where you can see documents and read them, but you cannot download them and copy. If it is something related to Adobe, then you will be able to download.

Comment: Some websites render the PDF's as JPG images for each page and then provide their own viewer to read those images. You could also convert the PDF to HTML (via third-party tools) and render that. Anyway, there is really no magic trick here. If your client doesn't want people to make copies. DON'T PUT THEM ON THE INTERNET!

Answer (score 5):

to put it simply: Any data that is displayed on a computer, to a user will have to be transmitted to their computer to be displayed. Therefore they will have that content on their computer and will be able to retain it.

You may find ways to make this hard, but you will never be able to make it impossible to do so and therefore not many publishers will grant you rights to publish in this manner.

Comment: I understand this and client also. I want to know what are those ways to make it to do harder (hard for normal users and not for professionals).

Comment: Firstly i would look into the legalities behind publishing and authors rights before advising a client. This as a professional and developer is your obligation.

Comment: All content is legal for publishing.

Comment: So, content is legal and I do not want it to be 100% readonly for sure (just harder to download / copy), so what are options here?